# Unable to make a call form JSSIP to my phone number and I have the CTI server credentials

Tags: webrtc, sip, jssip

I am working on CTI project I want to create cti phone for my company that can work fine with the company requirement, currently I am using following code for making call.

```
const JsSIP = require('jssip');
const NodeWebSocket = require('jssip-node-websocket');
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
JsSIP.debug.enable('JsSIP:*');


JsSIP.debug.enable('*');

function getAudioElement(id: string): HTMLAudioElement {
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!(el instanceof HTMLAudioElement)) {
    throw new Error(`Element "${id}" not found or not an audio element.`);
  }
  return el;
}


async function wait(ms: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}



function main() {

var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://PBX_server');
var configuration = {
  sockets  : [ socket ],
  uri      : 'sip:user@realm',
  password : 'pass'
  hack_ip_in_contact: true
};

var ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);
var currentSession;

ua.on('newRTCSession', function(e) {
        console.log("New Webrtc session created!");
        currentSession = e.session;
  });

ua.start();

var eventHandlers = {
  'progress': function(e) {
    console.log('call is in progress');
  },
  'failed': function(e) {
    console.log('call failed with cause: '+ e.cause);
  },
  'ended': function(e) {
    console.log('call ended with cause: '+ e.cause);
  },
  'confirmed': function(e) {
    console.log('call confirmed');
  }
};

var options = {
  'eventHandlers'    : eventHandlers,
  'mediaConstraints' : { 'audio': true, 'video': true }
};

var session = ua.call('sip:+923235037548@realm', options);
 
}


main();
```

after the call method I get following logs.

```
      common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface new() [url:"wss://sips_erver"] +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA new() [configuration:Object] +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport new() +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA configuration parameters after validation: +5ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - authorization_user: "user" +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - password: NOT SHOWN +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - realm: null +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - ha1: NOT SHOWN +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - authorization_jwt: NOT SHOWN +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - display_name: null +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - uri: sip:user@realm +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - contact_uri: {"_parameters":{"transport":"ws"},"_headers":{},"_scheme":"sip","_user":"kph8or3c","_host":"aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid","_port":null} +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - instance_id: "2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6" +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - use_preloaded_route: true +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - session_timers: true +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - session_timers_refresh_method: "UPDATE" +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - session_timers_force_refresher: false +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - no_answer_timeout: 60000 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - register: true +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - register_expires: 600 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - registrar_server: sip:realm +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - connection_recovery_max_interval: 30 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - connection_recovery_min_interval: 2 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA - via_host: "aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid" +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA start() +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport connect() +5ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface connect() +12ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface connecting to WebSocket wss://sips_erver +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:UA call() +2ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession new +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession connect() +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "peerconnection" +12ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession newRTCSession() +0ms
index.ts:76 New Webrtc session created!
contentScript.bundle.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Object
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface WebSocket wss://sips_erver connected +4s
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport send() +4s
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport sending message:REGISTER sip:realm SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:sips_erver;transport=ws;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9003902
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:user@realm>
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=bueer4e9s2
Call-ID: iaevuq10ujqmtlkgv46rgu
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:kph8or3c@aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6>";expires=600
Expires: 600
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: path,gruu,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 3.9.1
Content-Length: 0

 +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +3ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +195ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport received text message:SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9003902
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="realm",algorithm=MD5,nonce="1662070943:2bc3d57c75de600f76480a7e570a82cd",opaque="6465766963652e613233393935373531",qop="auth"
To: <sip:user@realm>;tag=3_uTW3IPsEY.
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=bueer4e9s2
Call-ID: iaevuq10ujqmtlkgv46rgu
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Content-Length: 0

 +195ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | using qop=auth [a2:"REGISTER:sip:realm"] +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | response generated +2ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport send() +28ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport sending message:REGISTER sip:realm SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:sips_erver;transport=ws;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6872321
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:user@realm>
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=bueer4e9s2
Call-ID: iaevuq10ujqmtlkgv46rgu
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Proxy-Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="user", realm="realm", nonce="1662070943:2bc3d57c75de600f76480a7e570a82cd", uri="sip:realm", response="5df9943ccb8a5aed183f472c61d9c50a", opaque="6465766963652e613233393935373531", qop=auth, cnonce="i1u09jm547vs", nc=00000001
Contact: <sip:kph8or3c@aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;transport=ws>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6>";expires=600
Expires: 600
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: path,gruu,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 3.9.1
Content-Length: 0

 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +28ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +279ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport received text message:SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6872321
Require: outbound
Contact: <sip:kph8or3c@aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;transport=ws>;expires=600;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6>";pub-gruu="sip:user@realm;gr=oburn:uuid:2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6";temp-gruu="sip:user@realm;gr=oburn:uuid:2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6";+sip.ice;flow-id=1;gruu="sip:user@realm;gr=oburn:uuid:2508be13-bf62-43eb-a096-1f2f6a5c7de6"
Contact: <sip:user@135.181.57.98:59771;ob;transport=TLS>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-00002116c300>";expires=210;flow-id=1
To: <sip:user@realm>;tag=7CQtXkDLVbIhAA..
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=bueer4e9s2
Call-ID: iaevuq10ujqmtlkgv46rgu
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Flow-Timer: 30
Content-Length: 0

 +279ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession session connecting +5s
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "connecting" +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession createLocalDescription() +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "sdp" +132ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "sending" [request:InitialOutgoingInviteRequest] +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport send() +996ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport sending message:INVITE sip:+923235037548@realm SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:sips_erver;transport=ws;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6354034
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1468 INVITE
Contact: <sip:kph8or3c@aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Session-Expires: 90
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: timer,gruu,ice,replaces,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 3.9.1
Content-Length: 6666

v=0
o=- 3179881977689588009 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400
m=audio 49400 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 192.168.224.1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2868209204 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.224.1 49400 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:4200540781 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.18.28 49401 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:3832978116 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.224.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:3034371741 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.18.28 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:uM69
a=ice-pwd:Lv0QIGDWNe6ivMv8kAJMJ5VM
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A1:EA:2E:13:DB:9C:61:EA:11:DB:4E:21:EE:28:C3:B3:B6:CC:E0:E3:0B:8C:FD:F1:A2:50:0A:CA:F0:FF:4E:A0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=sendrecv
a=msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 4a36b04b-b141-4ac9-bf5e-bc901782d124
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2
a=fmtp:63 111/111
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:2855336486 cname:PU+8Yc7wb7+U9BBI
a=ssrc:2855336486 msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 4a36b04b-b141-4ac9-bf5e-bc901782d124
m=video 49402 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 35 36 41 42 98 99 100 101 114 115 116 117 118
c=IN IP4 192.168.224.1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2868209204 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.224.1 49402 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:4200540781 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.18.28 49403 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:3832978116 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.224.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:3034371741 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.18.28 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:uM69
a=ice-pwd:Lv0QIGDWNe6ivMv8kAJMJ5VM
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A1:EA:2E:13:DB:9C:61:EA:11:DB:4E:21:EE:28:C3:B3:B6:CC:E0:E3:0B:8C:FD:F1:A2:50:0A:CA:F0:FF:4E:A0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 0bbe7300-5c36-459f-b66d-65a069ba7dcf
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:35 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli
a=fmtp:35 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:36 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:36 apt=35
a=rtpmap:41 AV1/90000
a=rtcp-fb:41 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:41 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:41 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack pli
a=rtpmap:42 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:42 apt=41
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:114 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:114 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:114 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:114 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack pli
a=fmtp:114 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=rtpmap:115 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:115 apt=114
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:117 apt=116
a=rtpmap:118 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 3849983765 2848192372
a=ssrc:3849983765 cname:PU+8Yc7wb7+U9BBI
a=ssrc:3849983765 msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 0bbe7300-5c36-459f-b66d-65a069ba7dcf
a=ssrc:2848192372 cname:PU+8Yc7wb7+U9BBI
a=ssrc:2848192372 msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 0bbe7300-5c36-459f-b66d-65a069ba7dcf
 +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +997ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +233ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport received text message:SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6354034
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="realm",algorithm=MD5,nonce="1662070945:efa19eeed9ddfb207d74ef8ec19efc90",opaque="6465766963652e613233393935373531",qop="auth"
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>;tag=q57zNvS6vkY.
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1468 INVITE
Content-Length: 0

 +233ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport send() +2ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport sending message:ACK sip:+923235037548@realm SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:sips_erver;transport=ws;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6354034
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>;tag=q57zNvS6vkY.
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1468 ACK
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 3.9.1
Content-Length: 0

 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +2ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | using qop=auth [a2:"INVITE:sip:+923235037548@realm"] +2s
common.js:113 JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | response generated +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport send() +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport sending message:INVITE sip:+923235037548@realm SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:sips_erver;transport=ws;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5475645
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1469 INVITE
Proxy-Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="user", realm="realm", nonce="1662070945:efa19eeed9ddfb207d74ef8ec19efc90", uri="sip:+923235037548@realm", response="b0c42fb27c55b2de69f64a2168f6a24b", opaque="6465766963652e613233393935373531", qop=auth, cnonce="cokk9v6ljlal", nc=00000001
Contact: <sip:kph8or3c@aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;transport=ws;ob>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Session-Expires: 90
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: timer,gruu,ice,replaces,outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 3.9.1
Content-Length: 6666

v=0
o=- 3179881977689588009 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400
m=audio 49400 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 192.168.224.1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2868209204 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.224.1 49400 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:4200540781 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.18.28 49401 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:3832978116 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.224.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:3034371741 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.18.28 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:uM69
a=ice-pwd:Lv0QIGDWNe6ivMv8kAJMJ5VM
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A1:EA:2E:13:DB:9C:61:EA:11:DB:4E:21:EE:28:C3:B3:B6:CC:E0:E3:0B:8C:FD:F1:A2:50:0A:CA:F0:FF:4E:A0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=sendrecv
a=msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 4a36b04b-b141-4ac9-bf5e-bc901782d124
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2
a=fmtp:63 111/111
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:2855336486 cname:PU+8Yc7wb7+U9BBI
a=ssrc:2855336486 msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 4a36b04b-b141-4ac9-bf5e-bc901782d124
m=video 49402 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 35 36 41 42 98 99 100 101 114 115 116 117 118
c=IN IP4 192.168.224.1
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:2868209204 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.224.1 49402 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:4200540781 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.18.28 49403 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=candidate:3832978116 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.224.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:3034371741 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.18.28 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:uM69
a=ice-pwd:Lv0QIGDWNe6ivMv8kAJMJ5VM
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A1:EA:2E:13:DB:9C:61:EA:11:DB:4E:21:EE:28:C3:B3:B6:CC:E0:E3:0B:8C:FD:F1:A2:50:0A:CA:F0:FF:4E:A0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 0bbe7300-5c36-459f-b66d-65a069ba7dcf
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:35 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli
a=fmtp:35 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:36 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:36 apt=35
a=rtpmap:41 AV1/90000
a=rtcp-fb:41 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:41 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:41 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack pli
a=rtpmap:42 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:42 apt=41
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:114 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:114 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:114 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:114 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack pli
a=fmtp:114 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=rtpmap:115 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:115 apt=114
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:117 apt=116
a=rtpmap:118 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 3849983765 2848192372
a=ssrc:3849983765 cname:PU+8Yc7wb7+U9BBI
a=ssrc:3849983765 msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 0bbe7300-5c36-459f-b66d-65a069ba7dcf
a=ssrc:2848192372 cname:PU+8Yc7wb7+U9BBI
a=ssrc:2848192372 msid:rFgyXrRpaRkNUFrMwEEmuA6k551YE3si8400 0bbe7300-5c36-459f-b66d-65a069ba7dcf
 +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +2ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction Timer D expired for transaction z9hG4bK6354034 +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +201ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport received text message:SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5475645
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1469 INVITE
Content-Length: 0

 +201ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +441ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +56ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport received text message:SIP/2.0 400 Bad Request
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5475645
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>;tag=ZTLYShPJ4bEhAA..
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1469 INVITE
Allow: NOTIFY, REFER, INFO, ACK, BYE, INVITE, OPTIONS, CANCEL
Supported: recording
Reason: SIP;cause=400;text="Bad Request"
P-Asserted-Identity: <tel:00923235037548;phone-context=realm>
X-Telepo-CTI-Call-ID: b3621205-a822-4e3f-982a-b349dbe2b3f3
Content-Length: 0

 +56ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport send() +2ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:Transport sending message:ACK sip:+923235037548@realm SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:sips_erver;transport=ws;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/WSS aic3ao0nhgpg.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5475645
Max-Forwards: 69
To: <sip:+923235037548@realm>;tag=ZTLYShPJ4bEhAA..
From: <sip:user@realm>;tag=d5p8tdji4d
Call-ID: 7ilh4875rfrqdq30k0f5
CSeq: 1469 ACK
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO,NOTIFY
Supported: outbound
User-Agent: JsSIP 3.9.1
Content-Length: 0

 +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +3ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +58ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession session failed +1ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "_failed" +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession close() +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession close() | closing local MediaStream +0ms
common.js:113 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "failed" +5ms
index.ts:87 call failed with cause: SIP Failure Code
common.js:113 JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction Timer D expired for transaction z9hG4bK5475645 +267ms
```

I don't have the sip-server access the only thing I have just credentials that is shared with, But there is another package **sip.js** that was giving me the same issue.
but got resolve with the parameter inveiteWithOutSdp=ture.
but I don't know how to do this JSSIP.
and keep in mind that I am dialing to my own Mobile Phone number that call is sip->GSM number not the SIP->SIP call.
thanks advance.

Regards,